# Aws serverless: one authorizer for each function

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, serverless

I'm using AWS + Serverless + JS and I don't want to define authorizer for each function separately. What would you suggest to resoolve this issue?

```
service: iot-server-2
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  httpApi:
    authorizers:
      customAuthorizer:
        type: request
        functionName: authorizerFunc

functions:
  api:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
          authorizer:      <-- I DON'T WANT THIS HERE
            name: customAuthorizer
  getDevice:
      handler: sensor-save-data-handler.handler
      events:
        - httpApi:
            path: /sensors
            method: get
            authorizer:     <-- I DON'T WANT THIS HERE
              name: customAuthorizer

  authorizerFunc:
    handler: authorizer.handler
```